# determine if CGpath/CGcontext intersect with CGpoint?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cgcontext, cgpath

I have googled around now for awhile and i haven't seem to find a good answer for this. I only found a template about path intersection, but it's a bit too complicated and not really what I'm looking for since i only need a function that returns a BOOL with YES or NO.

```
//This is my code so far. Its getting called every time the touch is moved.
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 568));
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 8.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), greentmporary.x, greentmporary.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), greenpoint1.x, greenpoint1.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


    [drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How you determine cgcontextintersection of two lines. Sorry i should have been more clear

Comment: How about some maths? [Line-line intersection (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection)

Comment: I think in this case its pretty hard to determine with only basic maths. I need something like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3282996/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2024%20feb%202014%2020.11.22.png)

Comment: It all boils down to (more or less) basic maths at some point ;)

Comment: Are you asking about a series of lines or are there curves and arcs and in the two paths? Do you want to know *if* they intersect or *where* they intersect? Are the paths continuous or do they contain gaps (CGPathMoveToPoint)? Do you include the line width in the intersection (I see that you have quite a wide line in your code)? Do you have the paths as CGPaths object or do you have the array of points / control points that create them?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking wether segments intersect or not.

You can solve this by checking if values belongs to intervals.

Your segments (lines) intersect if and only if
the x intervals overlaps and the y intervals overlap each other.

Line A - x goes from x1A to x2A - y goes from y1A to y2A
Line B - x goes from x1B to x2B - y goes from y1B to y2B

means points are (x1A, y1A) (x2A, y2A)
means points are (x1B, y1B) (x2B, y2B)

They intersect if

( x1B ≤ x1A ≤ x2B   OR   x1B ≤ x2A ≤ x2B )

AND

( y1B ≤ y1A ≤ y2B   OR   y1B ≤ y2A ≤ y2B )

If you look for intersection of paths made by a set of segments you can simply loop over all the segments of your path A and check if there is an intersection with one of the segments of B. The time complexity will be quadratic and then not scalable to big paths.

But after this 1st brute force approach you can try to reduce the problem for example by only applying the search on the segments that intersect the intersections of the 2 paths bounding boxes (means which have at least one point inside it). Finding the bounding boxes is equivalent to search the min and max of the x and y of your points.

Comment: As i said earlier, its not just two lines, its many lines put together in a CGcontext.

Comment: Ah Ok. It is a bit more complicated then. Let a bit of time.

Comment: That would probably cause a momoryleak since the line is probably made out of millions of cgpoints.

Comment: Oh I see. The memory is not a problem here but the computing time will be an issue. But it also depends on how much the bounding boxes overlap. The less they overlap the less points you will have to take in account.

Comment: found something that make work  if (CGPathContainsPoint(<#CGPathRef path#>, <#const CGAffineTransform *m#>, <#CGPoint point#>, <#bool eoFill#>)) {
        <#statements#>
    }

Comment: The doc says "A point is contained in a path if it would be inside the painted region when the path is filled." Is that what you need? " 2 paths can be inside each other without intersecting.

Comment: @VincentZgueb, I implemented your math but it doesn't seem to function properly. I've done a fair amount of debugging and am fairly certain that I've implemented it to match. Can you glance at it? Line 116 at https://github.com/zakkhoyt/RedBlueLines/blob/master/RedBlueLines/RBView.swift